# Usage of "ain't"?

Tags: word-usage, contractions, aint

As far as I understand, "ain't" can mean either "isn't" (ain't no sunshine) or "hasn't" (you ain't seen nothing yet).

Are there any rules when "ain't" is used? Does it have a different meaning than "isn't" or "hasn't"?

**Edit**: Maybe asking for rules was not the best idea. A better question would have been: when do *you* use "ain't" instead of "isn't"/"hasn't"?

Answer (score 15):

*Ain't* is used as a regular negated form of *be* or *have*, and supposedly sometimes *do*:

- I ain't no tractor. = I am not a tractor.
- I ain't got no tractor. = I haven't got any tractor.

It's also used like *there isn't*, by common omission of *there* from *there ain't*.

- Ain't no tractor here. = There isn't any tractor here.

And in case you hadn't guessed, dialects that use *ain't* stereotypically use [negative concord](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_negative) as well.

Comment: It doesn't always have to be used with negative concord: "It ain't that kind of party." "I ain't sure which one I want." "Ain't that a shame." And so on.

Comment: @Robusto: Of course. I was just having some fun. :P

Answer (score 1):

I was taught that "ain't" is a contraction of "am not."  Its wide misuse has caused it to be considered slang.

Answer (score 0):

In response to your edit, the best time to use [ain't](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ain%27t) is to catch attention or to gain emphasis.