# Ain't and gotta

Tags: meaning-in-context, slang, contractions

I have a sentence below:

> You ain't gotta believe me.

In this sentence, If i'm not wrong, Does **ain't** mean **have not**? and Does **gotta** mean **got to**?

So, it means *You have not got to believe me*. I'm I correct?

Comment: I generally translate "ain't" as "is not" or "are not", but it's really quite "flexible".  For the above I'd translate it as "do not".

Comment: I gather  it means "you don't have to believe me".

Comment: As @HotLicks says, "ain't" can be used as a general negation, it's not always a contraction of the same verb.

Comment: @Bamar When is ain't a negation and not a contraction?

Comment: OP showed her research ("Does ain't mean have not? and Does gotta mean got to?") and the question is clear; but I'm voting to close as duplicate: https://english.stackexchange.com/q/29755/112436

Comment: @Lambie - It's not always a contraction *of the same verb*.  (In fact, in terms of linguistics, it's probably its own unique verb, vs a contraction of any "normal" ones.  I'm thinking that some British dialects would accept a sentence roughly like "That ae a good looking boat!")

Comment: My question ****was to Bamar*** about his statement.  Also, I say "translate" for the benefit of the OP, as generally I don't translate it in fact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are correct.  Most fluent English speakers would say in formal grammar:

> You do not have to believe me.

Comment: I appreciate...

Comment: I agree that it means, "You do not have to believe me."  I disagree where you write "You are correct."

Answer (score 0):

*ain't* translates  into standard English as: is/are not.

*gotta* translates as: *have got to* or *have to*, the two ways to say *have* in English and where *to have* to or *have got to* means *be obliged to do something.*

ain't gotta: do not have to [verb] or have not got to [verb].

Example: He ain't gotta go today.

Translation; He does not have to go today. OR He hasn't got to go today.