# The usage of word "ain't"

Tags: word-usage

What is the use of ain't and "not/no" in a single phrase? The question is that we usually use ain't in our writings, but when it comes to a usual expression "ain't not" or "ain't no" does the meaning differ from the one which means have not, do not, am not etc.?

Comment: Since *ain't* is nonstandard, I doubt there are general rules about it.  You have to know the dialect to interpret.  For example, I would say "This ain't no fun" means the same as "This ain't fun", with the double-negative only for emphasis.

Comment: @GEdgar "I aint not never done nuffink to no one", was the catch phrase of someone, perhaps Sergeant Snudge, trying to affect an officer's accent in *The Army Game* circa 1960.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/29755/usage-of-aint

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Usage of "ain't"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/29755/usage-of-aint)

Comment: The meaning does not differ. The register does. And some will argue that the register very much is part of the meaning. That's why code-switching is a thing.